# How to continuously rotate a bivariate normal distribution by changing its correlation matrix?

Tags: normal-distribution

I want to create an animation in which a bivariate normal distribution rotate in xy plane by using `matplotlib`.

I don't want to alter the variances in the two principal components, all I want is to rotate the two principal components at the same pace.

How the correlation matrix should evolve in order to achieve this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Suppose your initial covariance matrix is $\Sigma$.

Let $R=\begin{bmatrix} \cos\theta & \sin \theta \\ -\sin \theta & \cos \theta \end{bmatrix}$.

Verify that $R\Sigma R^T$ rotates the principal component as $\theta$ changes. Try to prove this using eigenvalue decomposition of $\Sigma$.